# Space issue when toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to multi column accordion but I am facing gap issues when expanding. Please see:

[image: attached screen shot]

and JS Fiddle link `HTML,` https://jsfiddle.net/rub3k4h4/

Comment: So you want that when you click for example FP1 and it expands, FP2 should also expand? or just the left side should expand and the left stays static?

Comment: The section with the space issue, do you want the un-expanded accordions to stay to the top?

Comment: no actually i want FP2 not to go down and stay its original position.

Comment: You should then wrap each of the columns in a different div.

Comment: when we click on left side FP1 its expanding, at same time right side **space** coming that is main problem for me. the right side FP2 stay original position.

Comment: ya we can wrap each of the columns but without touching existing Div structure we are trying to fix. is there any alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want if you use `display:inline-block`
You should put your accordion in two separate columns, which you will align as you like (I used float):

```
<div> //outer container
    <div id="col1"> //left list container
        <ul id="wrap">
            <li class="race-class toggle-col">FP1
                <div class="col11"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">/* your list right here */</div> //right list container
</div>
```

And your JS can be as simple as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li > div[class^=col]").hide();
    $(".toggle-col").click(function(){
        $(this).find("[class^=col]").toggle();
    });
});
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rub3k4h4/3/)